# Как создать пользовательское событие?

Tags: javascript, node.js

У телеграмм библиотеки node js есть `onText` это функция или это событие? Если это событие, то подскажите пожалуйста, как создать такое на JavaScript, я нашёл только `addEventListener`

Answer (score -1):

Использовать **[CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent)**

```js
const helloEvent = new CustomEvent('hello');

// Подписка на событие
document.addEventListener('hello', (e) => alert('событие сработало'));

// Триггер события
document.dispatchEvent(helloEvent);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139638/discussion-on-answer-by------).